# Twig Loader Namespacing

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am slowly refactoring my code, and I am using TWIG for my templating "engine" in PHP. My current directory structure in my application is as follows (PSR-4) -

```
src/ 
    Test/
        User/
            Resources/
                views/
     Test/
        Core/
            Resources/
                views/
```

I am using the following code to load TWIG -

```
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
    dirname(__DIR__). '/src/Test'
));
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => dirname(__DIR__). '/app/storage/cache',
    'debug' => true,
));
```

Currently, it works fine and allows me to call each TWIG file like -

```
echo $twig->render('User\Resources\views\partials\sidebar.html.twig', $data);
```

Although, typing all of that is time consuming, and I would like to simplify it. Is there anyway to do it how Symfony autoloads bundles?

I have attempted to use this in my loader as well, but if there are similar directories in the views folder everything is overwritten by the first view found. For example - Core/Resources/views/partials/sidebar.twig would be used instead of User/Resources/views/partials/sidebar.twig

```
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(array(
            dirname(__DIR__). '/src/Test/Core/Resources/views',
            dirname(__DIR__). '/src/Test/User/Resources/views',
    ));
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are, it is called Twig namespaces: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#built-in-loaders

```
$loader->addPath(dirname(__DIR__).'/src/Test/Core/Resources/views', 'core');
$loader->addPath( dirname(__DIR__). '/src/Test/User/Resources/views', 'user');
```

Now your paths are like `@user/partials/sidebar.html.twig`, `@core/...`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much! That made a worlds difference.

Answer (score 2):

Darn it.  @Wouter J beat me again! Oh well.

Twig namespaces will allow you to abbreviate your template paths.  The same namespace can point to multiple directories so you can control the order in which the directories are searched.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Here is an example for app/config/config.yml

```
twig:
paths:
    "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Cerad/Bundle/AppBundle/Resources/views/CeradGame": CeradGame
    "%kernel.root_dir%/../../cerad2/src/Cerad/Bundle/GameBundle/Action":         CeradGame
```

So templates starting with @CeradGame will be looked for in the above two directories.

If you need more control than what the config file provides then you can also use a compiler pass(http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to set things:

```
class Pass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $bundleDirAction = $container->getParameter('cerad_api01__bundle_dir') . '/Action';

    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition = $container->getDefinition('twig.loader.filesystem');

    $twigFilesystemLoaderDefinition->addMethodCall('addPath', array($bundleDirAction, 'CeradApi01'));        
}
```

Finally, it can be a bit challenging to determine the exact twig paths.  Here is a command for dumping them from the command line:

```
class TwigCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
protected function configure()
{
    $this
        ->setName       ('twig:paths')
        ->setDescription('Twig Paths')
   ;
}
protected function getService($id)     { return $this->getContainer()->get($id); }
protected function getParameter($name) { return $this->getContainer()->getParameter($name); }

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $loader = $this->getService('twig.loader');
    $namespaces = $loader->getNamespaces();
    foreach($namespaces as $namespace)
    {
        $paths = $loader->getPaths($namespace);
        foreach($paths as $path)
        {
          //if (substr($namespace,0,5) == 'Cerad') echo sprintf("NS %-12s %s\n",$namespace,$path);
            echo sprintf("NS %-12s %s\n",$namespace,$path);
        }
    }
    return;

    $exists = $loader->exists('@CeradTourn/Tourn/Welcome/TournWelcomeInde.html.twig');
    if ($exists) echo "Found it\n";
    else         echo "Not found\n";
}
```

I wrote the command some time ago.  There might be something similar in the twig bundle.

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot Cerad. I am actually not using symfony, but I appreciate the information.

Comment: Yep.  The Symfony2 tag threw me but I'll leave this here just for my own documentation.